# python discord bot change_presence not working

Tags: python, android-activity, discord, disnake

I am writing a discord bot on the disnake library and I want to change its status, but when I want to enter additional parameters details, state or put an image for activity, only the name parameter is displayed. Also, if you set the streaming activity type, then the streamer activity icon is also not shown and the details parameter

I tried changing links, images, but nothing helped

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [mre]. Add more context to you question by adding the appropriate code in your question as text.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the code with which you change the status, but as an option give a try:

```
from disnake import Activity, ActivityType

activity = Activity(type=ActivityType.playing, name="a game")
await bot.change_presence(activity=activity)
```